# MVVM Binding one ComboBox from another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I am pretty new into MVVM and I wanted to ask, if you could help me getting the SelectedValue from a ComboBox to my VM-Class. In my example I have a ComboBox with all the car brands. If I select a car brand I want to have all the models from the car brand in another ComboBox to choose from. I've already made some research but I couldnt find a single solution to my problem.

[After clicking on the Brand-ComboBox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHupR.png)

This is fine so far, but when I want to have the models displayed, the ComboBox stays empty.

Code from my **View-Class**:`

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="vmcars" ObjectType="{x:Type local:VMCars}"/>

<!--MainGrid-->
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vmcars}">
.
.
.
.
</Grid>
```

Code from my **Brand-ComboBox**:

```
        <!--CarBrand Combobox-->
        <ComboBox x:Name="carBrand" Style="{StaticResource combobox}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AllCars}"
                  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                  DisplayMemberPath="c_brand"
                  Margin="20,13,17,15" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30">
            <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
                <Binding Path="SelectedBrand"                  
                         BindsDirectlyToSource="True"                  
                         Mode="OneWayToSource" />
            </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

Code from my **Model-ComboBox**:

```
        <!--CarModel ComboBox-->
        <ComboBox x:Name="carModel" Style="{StaticResource combobox}" Grid.Column="1"
                  Margin="20,15,17,14"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ModelSelectedBrand}" DisplayMemberPath="c_model"
                  Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30">
        </ComboBox>
```

Code from my **VMClass**:

```
    public string selectedBrand;
    public string SelectedBrand
    {
        get { return selectedBrand; }
        set
        {
            selectedBrand = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs
                               ("ModelSelectedBrand"));

        }
    }

        public IEnumerable<c_car> ModelSelectedBrand             
    {
        get
        {
            return (from c in db.c_car
                    where c.c_brand.Equals(SelectedBrand) //THIS IS CAUSING PROBLEMS

                    select c).GroupBy(x=>x.c_model).Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(x=>x.c_model).ToList();  
        }
    }
```

When I then comment the **WHERE** clause in my Linq statement, I get this result:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grm04.png)

These are **all** the car models.

I think the problem is that my "**SelectedBrand**" Property doesnt get any value from the **carBrand-ComboBox**

Therefore, I wanted to ask you, if anybody has an idea what might cause the trouble.

Comment: Why do you comment WHERE clause? Do you have compile time error in your where statement or have you another unexpected result with it?

Comment: Before commenting the WHERE clause it didn't display any models inside of my ComboBox.. The commenting was just an example to show you that the SelectedBrand Property doesn't receive any SelectedItem from the Brand-ComboBox.

Comment: It looks like your c_brand value or SelectedBrand value is null or it has not same values. You can add a new breakpoint to this row to show SelectedBrand value (your code looks fine and it should contains actual selected value and collection of cars and its c_brand values to concretes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your car brand `ComboBox` is currently passing the class name of `c.car` to your query. If you bind to `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`, and set `SelectedValuePath` to `"c_car"` it works.

So your new CarBrand ComboBox definition will be

```
<!--CarBrand Combobox-->
<ComboBox x:Name="carBrand" Style="{StaticResource combobox}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding AllCars}"
          Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
          DisplayMemberPath="c_brand"
          SelectedValuePath="c_brand"
          Margin="20,13,17,15" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30">
    <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
        <Binding Path="SelectedBrand"                  
                 BindsDirectlyToSource="True"                  
                 Mode="OneWayToSource" />
    </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked after I deleted the `                 BindsDirectlyToSource="True"                  
                 Mode="OneWayToSource"`.

Comment: Good to hear. No problem.